# Objective-C. DismissVC with the delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a VC, lets call it *UserInfoVC*, that is a subclass of *UIViewController*. That *UserInfoVC* holds another *UIView*. That *UIView* holds a *UIButton*.
With the custom protocol, from that *UIView* with the *UIButton*, when the button is tapped, I would like to dismiss that *UserInfoVC* (vc was presented modally).

So I have created that method in my *UserInfoVC*

```
-(void)dismissVC {
    [self dismissVC];
}
```

Next, the method is called from protocol method like this:

```
- (void)didTapGetFollowersForUser:(User *)user {
    if (self.user.followers == 0) {
        NSLog(@"No followers for that guy, sorry");
    } else {
        [self dismissVC];
        [self.delegate didRequestFollowersForUsername:user.login];
    }
}
```

I am getting that error form `[self dismissVC]` line: *Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16cb87ff0)*

I would like to add that I am currently learning Objective-C. I am trying to translate some of my previous projects and see the differences. The exact same code in Swift works just fine for me.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you created an infinite loop with this method:

```
-(void)dismissVC {
    [self dismissVC];
}
```

`[self dismissVC]` call will invoke the same method.

Comment: Thank you mate I don't know how I did not see it!

Comment: Do you happen to know why it does not work by creating a method inside my VC and calling it from the protocol method? I created it like this and called and same error persist
-(void)dismissVCModally {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: you can't dismiss the same UIViewController, dismiss has to be invoked in the ViewController which presented `UserInfoVC`

Comment: I am looking at the code from the course I've been following for programming in Swift. The very same method works there. Do you happen to know what makes that difference?

Comment: your `UserInfoVC` is presented probably by another VC, let's call it `UsersVC`. the `dismissVCModally` method should invoke a method on `UsersVC`, which calls the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` method.
other option is to call `removeFromParent` in `UserInfoVC` instead of `dismissViewControllerAnimated`